# Creating a tabular with guitar tablature diagrams

Tags: tables, songs

Friends, I'm using the [`songs`](http://songs.sourceforge.net/) package to write a songbook. Besides the lyrics part, there's also a command to create guitar tablature diagrams:

```
\gtab{C}{X32010}
```

which will produce this diagram:

[image: C Major]

Now, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lyric]{songs}

\begin{document}

\gtab{C}{X32010}

\gtab{D}{XX0232}

\gtab{E}{022100}

\gtab{F}{XX3211}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to put these diagrams side by side, like in a `2x2` tabular. Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to do it.

I suspect that the `\gtab` command forces a new line or something and breaks the tabular environment.

There are other packages on guitar tablatures, like `songbook` or `gchords`. But since I'm already using a package which has this feature, I'd like to stick with it.

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: Have you tried with the `gtab` command inside a `minipage`?

Comment: @YuppieNetworking: I tried, but I had no luck on using it. TBH, I was relying on `minipage` to save my code. `=)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just enclose them in braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
{\gtab{C}{X32010}} &
{\gtab{D}{XX0232}}\\
{\gtab{E}{022100}} &
{\gtab{F}{XX3211}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks Alan! I had no idea of that. Cheers! `=)`

Comment: @Paulo Braces are often a way out of these kinds of things, since they effectively limit whatever changes a macro is doing to within the braces.

Comment: I was really unaware of, I always thought the "additional braces" wouldn't make a difference. Thanks for the great explanation! `=)`